# Thévenin: Weird instructions

Tags: thevenin

Our professor provided us instruction on how to determine the Thévenin equivalent. The only problem is that the method prescribed seems weird. Here are the instructions:

[image]

[image]

R1=1k, R2=2k, R3=3k, R4=4.3k, and RL=5.1k.

I do not understand the point of step 3. Why do you think the professor would want us to connect a 10 V DC source across the the load terminals?

The only purpose I can think of is that they want us to construct the Thévenin equivalent using a 10 V source rather than the VOC.

Comment: "*Why do you think the professor would want us to connect a 10V DC source across the the load terminals?*" Well, because if you follow step 3 you will find that 10 V yields Id and therefore 10 V/Id must be the Thevenin impedance of the network as seen through terminals a and b. Which is what step 4 says. So the reason is given in the instructions. Not so?

Comment: I tried it out and it's actually true. Very cool! Thanks.

Comment: @periblepsis Solving it by hand I ran into the problem of calculating the equivalent resistance, REQ. When I remove the load resistance by opening the branch and disable the voltage sources by shorting them, I ran into the REQ being essentially undefined due to the resistors on either side of the circuit shorting out. Could this be why the professor asked us to find REQ using this method?

Comment: your question has no answer associated  with it

Comment: @Raquel No. You can get the equivalent resistance by summing the parallel of the left side with the parallel of the right side.

Comment: @jsotola the answer is that the 10V DC source divided by the current through, Id, will yield the equivalent resistance REQ.

Comment: @Raquel then write an answer ... writing a comment  is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

The experimental instructions exactly reflect the analytical approach for finding the Thevenin equivalent: those are (1) find open circuit voltage (2) suppress independent sources and attach a test source (3) use response from the test source to find internal resistance or impedance.

Answer (score 1):

#### quick high-level overview

Raquel, One of the problems we each face at some point when first learning about parts of the world we can't directly touch and feel with our own senses is about "breaking" wrong ideas we previously held, replacing them with better ideas.

One of the good ideas is to think of a voltage source as a **short** and to think of a current source as an **open**.

Let's see why:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frASuI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, before pressing the switch, there will be exactly \$10\:\text{mA}\$ in \$R\$. Same on the right, too.

But the moment we press the switch *on the left* the added \$5\:\text{mA}\$ goes straight through \$V_s\$ and bypasses \$R\$, entirely. \$V_s\$ acts like a **short** to this added current, all of which passes through \$V_s\$ to ground. \$R\$'s current stays perfectly the same as before. No change at all. So \$V_s\$ acts like a `short` to the newly added current.

It's even clearer to see this fact if you imagine that \$V_s\$ is a \$0\:\text{V}\$ voltage source. In that case, it's more obviously a short. All a voltage source does is to hold up some voltage difference between two nodes. This might be \$0\:\text{V}\$ or it might be some non-zero value. But regardless of what that value happens to be, it is effectively a dead short!

Hopefully, this helps you see that a voltage source is a short circuit, in some fashion.

The moment we press the switch *on the right* the added \$5\:\text{mA}\$ goes straight through \$R\$ and bypasses \$I_s\$, entirely. \$I_s\$ acts like an **open** to this added current, none of which passes through \$I_s\$ to ground instead forcing all of it to be added to \$R\$'s current. \$I_s\$'s current stays perfectly the same as before. No change at all. So \$I_s\$ acts like an `open` to the newly added current.

It's even clearer to see this fact if you imagine that \$I_s\$ is a \$0\:\text{A}\$ current source. In that case, it's more obviously an open. All a current source does is inject a current into a node. This might be \$0\:\text{A}\$ or it might be some non-zero value. But regardless of what that value happens to be, it is effectively doing so completely immune to any attempts to alter that value. Being immune is the same thing as having no conductance -- or infinite impedance.

Hopefully, this helps you see that a current source is an open circuit, in some fashion.

This is a way of understanding ***why*** a voltage source can be treated as a `short` and ***why*** a current source can be treated as an `open`.

#### your cases

It's easier to see your schematic as the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1UHx.png)</sup>

Each side can be reduced to the following Thevenin equivalents:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmQb9.png)</sup>

Here, it is pretty easy to see that the difference voltage will be about \$502.283\:\text{mV}\$ and the resistance will be the sum, or about \$2.4338\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

So that is what anything attached between \$a\$ and \$b\$ will `see`.

#### your instructions

One could either use a voltage source between \$a\$ and \$b\$ or a current source. Either method works fine. If you apply a voltage source, then measure the current, that gets the same result as if you apply a current source and measure the voltage difference. Regardless, the voltage difference divided by the current difference gets you the Thevenin impedance.

So there isn't just one way (using a voltage source) but actually two different ways. Both get you to the same place, though.

In the open-circuit case (removing \$R_{_\text{L}}\$), measuring the voltage difference between \$a\$ and \$b\$ will get you the Thevenin voltage. So that instruction gets the right result there.